# Find the last digit of a number raised to a certain power

Tags: c++, math

I am trying to find the unit digit of a number raised to a certain power, using the simplest method. I know about modular exponentiation. I am trying to implement something similar to [How to find the units digit of a certain power in a simplest way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7214419/how-to-find-the-units-digit-of-a-certain-power-in-a-simplest-way), but my code is showing the wrong answer for certain test cases in SPOJ. Here is the link to the question in SPOJ: http://www.spoj.com/problems/LASTDIG/

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int a2[] = {6, 2, 4, 8},
        a3[] = {1, 3, 9, 7},
        a4[] = {6, 4},
        a7[] = {1, 7, 9, 3},
        a8[] = {6, 8, 4, 2},
        a9[] = {1, 9},
        t;
    long long int b1, b2;

    cin >> t;

    while (t--) {
        cin >> b1 >> b2;
        b1 = b1 % 10;
        if (b2 == 0)
            cout << 1 << endl;
        else if (b1 == 0)
            cout << 0 << endl;
        else if (b2 == 1 || b1 == 5 || b1 == 6)
            cout << b1 << endl;
        else if (b1 == 2)
            cout << a2[b2 % 4] << endl;
        else if (b1 == 3)
            cout << a3[b2 % 4] << endl;
        else if (b1 == 4)
            cout << a4[b2 % 2] << endl;
        else if (b1 == 7)
            cout << a7[b2 % 4] << endl;
        else if (b1 == 8)
            cout << a8[b2 % 4] << endl;
        else if (b1 == 9)
            cout << a9[b2 % 2] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First

```
a7[]={1,7,0,3}
         ^^^
```

zero should be 9

```
a7[]={1,7,9,3}
```

And a9

```
a9[]={9,1}
      ^^^
```

should be reverse

```
a9[]={1,9}
```

Comment: I made both the changes. But its still showing wrong answer.

Comment: I have used long long int for that.

Comment: Did a test `b1:[0,999] ^ b2:[0,999]`, 1 million values, checking the result against the "manually" powered result. They all match.

Comment: The algo works. It's probably the output format to the site.