# Last digit in an exponent - wrong answer - C#

Tags: c#, algorithm

I was trying to solve this problem: http://www.spoj.com/problems/LASTDIG/ where it takes a base and exponent and I have to output the last digit of the result of theexponentiation, but online judge says that my program gives wrong answers though for typical test cases, my outputs are right.

N.B.: I have to use Fast Modular Exponentiation algorithm, here's a nice explanation for that: https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/cryptography/modarithmetic/a/fast-modular-exponentiation

```
using System;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int val = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        for (int i=0; i<val; i++ )
        {
            string input = Console.ReadLine();
            int a = Convert.ToInt32(input.Split()[0]);
            int b = Convert.ToInt32(input.Split()[1]);
            if (a==0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(0);
            } else if(b==0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(1);
            } else {
                a=a%10;
                string bToBinary=Convert.ToString(b, 2);
                double temp = 1;
                for(int j=bToBinary.Length-1, k=0; j>=0; j--, k++)
                {
                    if (bToBinary[j] == '1')
                    {
                        temp = temp*(Math.Pow(a, Math.Pow(2, k)));
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine(temp%10);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Sample Input:

```
4
3 10
6 2
14 11
1 0
```

Output from this program:

```
9
6
4
1
```

Comment: Did the judge provide you with the test cases used and their answers?

Comment: nope, it's sad and that's why I am here.

Comment: Fast Modular Exponentiation is not actually required here. The question demands only the last number which can be computed by looking at the last digit of base and figuring out the pattern in the last digits of its various exponents.

Comment: As shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7214528/106159 (Warning: Spoilers! ;)/

Comment: They are likely expecting integer math, and you're using floating point.

Comment: @hatchet could be, will give that a try.

Comment: Note that the exponent can be 2,147,483,000. A double will forget the last numbers, as it has a precision of only about 15 digits. So you will get 0 for large exponents - which probably will be wrong.

Comment: If you look on the right of the page with the problem, it states "Source limit: 700B". Your code as presented has over 900 characters.

Comment: It's already passed that 700B limit and ran on the server, then gave me the wrong answer.

Comment: Why I always need a lot of time to understand what is given and what is required from interview questions like this :(

Comment: This would be a stupid interview question, because it would amount to "do you happen to have come across this not particularly useful (to programmers) piece of mathematics?". A bit like the annoying interview question about detecting cycles in a linked list. Sometimes I wonder if the interviewer isn't just asking questions to make themselves look clever (when they almost certainly read the answer in a book or online without working it out themselves anyway...)

Comment: @MatthewWatson to me, those kind of questions are made to eliminate number of interviewees or to see who went through certain level of hard work. Nothing else.

Comment: @MatthewWatson You always start with the FooBar question and marvel at the number of programmers that cannot answer it.

Comment: @HansKesting you were right, the solution I had was getting overflow problem. For larger values like 9^2,147,483,000, no built in data types can't hold the value and that was the problem.

Comment: @juharr Did you mean "FizzBuzz question"?

Comment: @SharifMamun The "find a cycle in a linked list" question is, I feel, [not an appropriate interview question](http://www.nomachetejuggling.com/2014/06/24/the-worst-programming-interview-question/). ;)

Comment: @SimonForsberg "FooBar" is Microsoft's name for the "FizzBuzz" question, I believe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every power repeats either in either 1, 2 or 4.

Here is the pattern written out

```
1 = {1,1,1,1}
2 = {2,4,8,6}
3 = {3,9,7,1}
4 = {4,6,4,6}
5 = {5,5,5,5}
6 = {6,6,6,6}
7 = {7,9,3,1}
8 = {8,4,2,6}
9 = {9,1,9,1}
```

And as you already know the pattern for powers with the same unit e.g. the pattern for 13 is the same as for 3

So you should be able to write your program as such

```
public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int val = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        for (int i=0; i<val; i++ )
        {
            string input = Console.ReadLine();
            int a = Convert.ToInt32(input.Split()[0]);
            int b = Convert.ToInt32(input.Split()[1]);
            if (a==0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(0);
            } else if(b==0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(1);
            } else {
               Console.WriteLine (Math.Pow(a%10,b%4 + 4) %10);  
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There's a small problem. You are missing case when if (b%4 == 0) then b = 4; Anyways, I got the short explanation but you can describe a bit more for people who will come here in future. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @SharifMamun Yeah I missed that because I tested with a = 3. Adding 4 to the result will fix that and still keep the values small enough so you don't get overflow. e.g. a = 20 b = 2,147,483,000

Comment: This answer is missing any kind of proof that "Every power repeats either in either 1, 2 or 4", though. But there's one [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7214528/106159) (sort of).

Answer (score 0):

You aren't supposed to brute force the solution. The problem **specifically** ask for the **last digit** of the result, not the whole thing.

There is should be some kind of pattern in the multiplication that you can abuse. *Let's drop the power 0 for the moment, because that is a specific edge case.* For instance, we know that 10 or 20 to power of any positive integer will ends in 0, and 5 will always ends in 5. We can abuse this pattern, because no matter how many times we raise the power, the last digit will always be within this pattern.

The pattern can be extracted as such :

```
IEnumerable<int> FindExpLastDigitPattern(int i)
{
    var result = 1;

    var list = new List<int>();
    while (!list.Contains(result = (result * i) % 10))
    {
        list.Add(result);
        yield return result;
    }
}
```

And we can also predict the position within this pattern based on the power, which is `index = (power - 1) % pattern.Count`.

With that in mind, we can compute the last digit of an exponentiation :

```
int ComputeLastDigitOfExponentiation(int i, int power)
{
    // arguments guard...

    // handles specific case
    if (power == 0)  return 1;

    var pattern = FindExpLastDigitPattern(i).ToList();

    return pattern[(power - 1) % pattern.Count];
}
```